# Please re-run Magento compile command?

Tags: attribute-set, magento-2.0.5

I am trying to setup one of the magento 2 extension with cygwin which is from this source **https://github.com/ibnab/magento2-extension-change-attribute-set**
and I am getting this error during installion

PLEASE RE-RUN MAGENTO COMPILE COMMAND

> magento-2.0.5 - windows-7 X64 - terminal is = cygwin - opensshd is
>   installed correctly.

I really need to setup that extension.

thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 8):

Depending on your configuration it may also be unecessary.
If you are in `default` or `dev` mode you do not need it.

You just need it on `production` mode

From command line and from your Magento root path:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

P.S: After installing your module make sure you ran:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: In what succession should `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` be run?

Comment: setup:di:compile then setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command to start the compilation progress:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Sample output if you suceed:
[image]

If you dont have ssh access, you can create a PHP file to run compile command as follow

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
system('php bin/magento setup:di:compile');
echo "</pre>";
```

The go to that file to execute command
[image]

The compilation process will last for some minutes depends on the number of extensions on your Magento instance.

If you want to compile single module, take a look at this tutorial:
https://magentip.com/please-re-run-magento-compile-command-magento-2/

Hope this helps!